# TeamCity Quality metrics dashboard

Tags: rest, teamcity, dashboard, metrics

We use jetBrains **TeamCity** continuous integration server for builds.

We've got tens of different projects in TeamCity, and want to see one big picture across them in terms of their development quality, to find out which projects are lacking quality and in which sense. We use metrics such as unit test coverage, cyclomatic complexity \ maintainability index, duplicates, defect rates, etc...

We collect metrics to TeamCity from test tools, either:

1. automatically if supported by TeamCity as standard metrics (e.g. NCover coverage).
2. manually, extracting them when running test tools and providing them to TeamCity using service messages: `[##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='<valueTypeKey>' value='<value>']`

So we got them in TeamCity and can see them on per project charts. We can even get them out of TeamCity by REST protocol in XML or JSON format.

Our goal is to see the overall picture across ALL projects. Here are 2 examples of **tables** that we want to see:

- projects in rows, time (weeks) in columns, and values of one chosen metric in inside cells.
- projects in rows, all metrics in columns, values of the metrics in inside cells for a specific point in time (e.g. latest).

Or it could be a 2-dimensional **charts** with similar approach.

So, the question is:

Is there such existing Dashboard tool, that can show described tables and\or charts? Either separate application tightly integrated with TeamCity, or a plugin for TeamCity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is pretty similar to another one [I just answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844190/how-do-i-gather-teamcity-code-coverage-reports-from-multiple-projects-into-one-r).

The answer is to use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/).