# How do I gather TeamCity code coverage reports from multiple projects into one report?

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage, code-metrics

We use the build in coverage application in TeamCity 6 (about to upgrade to 7.1)
If we wish to see the code coverage (or other metrics) of a particular build it is fine as we can navigate to that build, but it would be great if we could pluck out a few interesting metrics from all/some of the current projects/build configurations and display them all together.

For convenience I would expect the new display to be accessible from within TeamCity itself, however if there are solutions that require a separate solution we could look at them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to compare a set of common metrics (e.g. code coverage) across different projects and over time then [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) is probably what you want.

You can integrate it with TeamCity by adding a [sonar-project.properties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Sonar+Runner) file to each project and calling [sonar-runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Runner) from a command line build step.

Comment: By the way, how good is Sonar for .NET projects? I've heard it's arisen in Java world and .NET functionality is not that good yet.

Comment: @Ivan, support for C# is quite good though I think it is fair to say it isn't at the same level as java yet.  There is a whole set of C# plugins that you can see in the documentation.  I'm not sure about .NET more broadly.  If you are going to try using it then you might want to read this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170780/teamcity-dotcover-report-path-for-sonar), it caused me a lot of pain.  I think I've fixed the link by the way.